# "message": "Unauthorized", Laravel authentication

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.3

This my function that I built for user login through API. Somehow it stopped logining users and it returns   `"message": "Unauthorized"`

Also the signup function returns same message.

```
public function postLogin(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only(['national_id', 'password']);
    $validator = Validator::make($credentials, [
        'national_id' => 'required'
    ]);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        throw new ValidationHttpException($validator->errors()->all());
    }
    try {
        if (!$token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
            return $this->response->errorUnauthorized();
        }
    } catch (JWTException $e) {
        return $this->response->error('could_not_create_token', 500);
    }
    return response()->json(compact('token'));
}
```

my route :

```
$api = app('Dingo\Api\Routing\Router');
$api->version('v1', function ($api) {
    $api->post('auth/postLogin', 'App\Api\V1\Controllers\AuthController@postLogin');
```

Comment: !$token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials) this is the line where you are getting the error. just tell me ffrom where $token is coming? and how are to passing it here to check with new token?

Comment: it's coming from JWTAuth library from a different class. @Exprator